# print duplicate names from set that entered by the user

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

The program should take a list of names from the user and convert all of the names to lower case, then should print all the duplicate names.

Here is my try, I need to take the input of the name from the user instead of writing myself.

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Sagio Mane");
    list.add("Karius");
    list.add("Mo Salah");
    list.add("Firmino");
    list.add("Lovren");
    list.add("Steven Gerrard");
    list.add("Karius");
    list.add("Mo Salah");

    Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
    for(String name : list) {
        if(s.add(name) == false)
            System.out.print(name + ", ");
```

Comment: One of your requirements was to convert all the names to lower case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have forgotten a "}" in the last for loop. The code works but you also need to convert the names to lower case so:

```
Set<String> s = new HashSet<>();
        for(String name : list) {
            name=name.toLowerCase(); //Convert all names to lowercase
            if (s.add(name) == false)
                System.out.print(name + ", ");
        }
```

*Also the `<String>` type reference doesn't need to be specified twice as done in the code line: `Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();` so you can remove it from the chevron brackets and use a **Diamond Inference** `<>` as shown in the above code.